# How to add clickable calendar widget to classic ASP page?

Tags: asp-classic, calendar

I normally work on ASP.net pages and I use the .net calendar control provided by Microsoft.  I find that it works well.

Someone asked me to add a clickable calendar widget to a classic ASP page, so I would like to know what is the easiest way to add a clickable calendar widget to a classic ASP page.  All I need is a calendar that the user clicks and then the date selected is copied into a text box on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Jquery UI, it has a nice calendar widget that is really easy to install.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: How can I use this to set a start date and an end date? I tried the code but could only set one date. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Double click On **Day Render Event** of your Calender widget
 and in the event handler try:

```
e.Day.IsSelectable = true;
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question.  I do not know how to add the calendar widget to my page.